# index.php executes directly by PHP from the user created for the website

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have a strange issue on CE 1.9.2.4. It happens in some random or undefined conditions and when happens it takes about a minute for the website to become unresponsive (because all CPUs are maxed out).

What I see in the tasks is that index.php is started directly by /usr/bin/php from the account used by the website (and these processes are increasing rapidly!), AFAIK index.php should only be requested by HTTP, so that is very strange.

I have searched the source of the project for some command which may start that by shell command, but had found nothing. It feels like it happens when a lot of cache is in the storage and when flushed or cleared partially but do not happens always. I have checked the cron configuration and it is fine.

Anyone have some suggestions/ideas?

Edit:
I have found that these processes are started from /usr/bin/php on HTTP POST requests but not on GET requests. The PHP_SAPI however returns cgi-fcgi when logged from index.php, is that normal? The actual problem is that sometimes from action in the admin panel which makes POST request, appears the problem of increasing of these processes.

Comment: strace your single process, in magento run profiler, also check access log to see why so many processes